# How to dispose JPanel?

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel

**The code below will be executed after clicking a button in my other class. How can I dispose this JPanel on any button?**

```
public class Final_Class extends JPanel {



public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


    g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    for(int a=0;a<upto;a++){
        if(a==7) g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        if(a==8) g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        if(a==9) g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        if(a==0) {g.fillRect(40, 110+x,Integer.parseInt(Burst[a])*5, 30);
                 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                 g.drawString("J".concat(Integer.toString(Jobs[a]+1)),40,105+x);
                 g.drawString(Burst[a], 35+CT[a]*5, 155+x);}
        if(a>0){ g.fillRect(40+CT[a-1]*5, 110+x,Integer.parseInt(Burst[a])*5, 30);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString("J".concat(Integer.toString(Jobs[a]+1)),40+CT[a-1]*5,105+x);
                g.drawString(Integer.toString(CT[a]), 35+CT[a]*5, 155+x);}
    }


}
```

Comment: `yourPanel.setVisible(false);` might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to remove a component from a container with `Container.remove(Component)`. You just need to keep a reference to the component.